# How to make the following tikz picture interactive?

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I am a newbie at using `Tikz`, so forgive my extended latex code. I am trying to recreate this image:

[image]

in `Beamer` using `Overlay` in such a way that first it just shows the green bulk region and then, on the click, the red boundary. A prototype that I tried is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{AdS/CFT}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\draw (2,5) -- (8,4);
\draw (2,-1) -- (8,0);
\draw (8,0) arc(-75:75:2.0675cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{AdS/CFT}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red!50!white] (2,2) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\draw[red, thick] (2,2) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\draw[red, thick] (2,5) -- (8,4);
\draw[red, thick] (2,-1) -- (8,0);
\draw[red, thick] (8,0) arc(-75:75:2.0675cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main methods how to animate a tikz drawing:

- the simple method is to use the overlay-awareness of tikz commands. For example if you want to draw something on the second overlay, you can use `\draw<2>`
- for more complex situations, you can use the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library. This allows you to use options like `fill on=<3->` to fill a shape on the 3rd overlay. For all possible options, see the documentation of the library at https://texdoc.org/serve/aobs-tikz.pdf/0

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red!50!white,fill on=<3->] (2,2) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\draw<2->[red, thick] (2,2) ellipse (1cm and 3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Just one query how can I fill blue colour in the region excluding the ellipse?

Comment: @codebpr Use `\fill[blue, thick] (2,-1) -- (8,0) arc(-75:75:2.0675cm) -- (2,5) -- cycle;` before you draw the ellipse